# How To Set React Modal border radius

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-modal

How do i change the border radius of [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal), i have given className `Modal` to the component and have defined the styles for the class but that does not seem to have any effect on the modal

```
<Modal
            className='Modal'
            isOpen={!!this.props.selectedProject}
            contnetLabel='Selected Option'
            onRequestClose={this.props.clearProjects}
            ariaHideApp={false}
            closeTimeoutMS={1000}
        >
</Modal>
```

SASS :

```
.Modal {
font-family: Raleway;
background-color: #242222;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
height: 90vh;
width: 50vw;
margin-right: -50%;
color: white;
border-radius: 400px;

h3 {
 color: white;
}
}
```

[Website link](https://5e2c8cf7b26a2cf95b40b0b8--thirsty-goldwasser-3dc847.netlify.com/) Modal is in my projects section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp).

```
.Modal {
  ...
    overflow: hidden;
  ...
}
```

Comment: on chrome this adds a blur due to transforms + hidden

Answer (score 1):

There's a prop called **contentClassName**
add this className with a unique name and in the style sheet, use that name independently as a selector and give the property **border-radius : *desired* px;**

here the contentClassName provides the className to modal-content, which covers your whole ModalHeader, body and Footer

for eg.

`<Modal contentClassName="custom-modal"></Modal>`

*style.scss*

`.custom-modal { border-radius: 10px !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I added a border radius to my Modal with Mantine in my React app. Its prop is called "radius"

```
<Modal opened={opened} onClose={close} radius='40px'>
```